# Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml' when running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

**Cannot find module 'js-yaml'**
Require stack:

- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\createExplorer.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro-config\src\loadConfig.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro-config\src\index.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro\src\commands\build.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-server\build\metro\importMetroFromProject.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-server\build\MetroDevServer.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\start\startDevServerAsync.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
  **Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'**
  Require stack:
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\createExplorer.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro-config\src\loadConfig.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro-config\src\index.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro\src\commands\build.js
- D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\metro\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-server\build\metro\importMetroFromProject.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\dev-server\build\MetroDevServer.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\start\startDevServerAsync.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\Ahsan Iqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js:5:14)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  **PS D:\REACT NATIVE\portfolio>**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install it? type npm install -g js-yaml in cmd

Comment: no currently i didn't try that. let me check that.